# Trigger event upon li click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to trigger a function upon users clicking on the li elements in the example below but not having much luck outside of using onclick - i.e. clicking on the first li (value of 1) would ideally call a function where the value "1" is passed in.

[Styled list control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1sO5.png)

```
..    
    <a href="#" class="path-nav-close"></a>
    <ul id='uItem'>
        <li><a href="#" class="launch" >1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="launch" onclick="alert('2')">2</a></li>

...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wL8vpuqt/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wL8vpuqt/6/

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL8vpuqt/7/)**.

You've just to prevent default behavior by using `event.preventDefault()` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#uItem li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#uItem li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
/* line 81, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav {
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  position: fixed;
}
/* line 87, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left {
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
/* line 93, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right {
  top: 26px;
  right: 26px;
}
/* line 100, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 6px solid white;
  background: #44403d;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* line 127, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.active a {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* line 137, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 8.5px;
  left: 8.5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* line 147, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(1) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.175s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.175s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.175s;
  transition-delay: 0.175s;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.14s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.14s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.14s;
  transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.105s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.105s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.105s;
  transition-delay: 0.105s;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.07s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.07s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.07s;
  transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(5) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.035s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.035s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.035s;
  transition-delay: 0.035s;
}
/* line 155, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav li:nth-child(6) {
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
/* line 169, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav:target li {
  -moz-transform: rotate(1800deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1800deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(1800deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1800deg);
  transform: rotate(1800deg);
}
/* line 174, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav:target .cross {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(1) {
  top: -100px;
  left: 80px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100px;
  left: 150px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(3) {
  top: -100px;
  left: 220px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(4) {
  top: -30px;
  left: 80px;
  
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(5) {
  top: -30px;
  left: 150px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(6) {
  top: -30px;
  left: 220px;
}


/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(7) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 80px;
}

/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(8) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 150px;
}

/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(9) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 220px;
}

/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-bottom-left:target li:nth-child(10) {
  top: 110px;
  left: 150px;
}




/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right:target li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 265px;
  left: 0px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right:target li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 252px;
  left: -82px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right:target li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 214px;
  left: -156px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right:target li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 156px;
  left: -214px;
}
/* line 73, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav.path-nav-top-right:target li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 82px;
  left: -252px;
}
/* line 200, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander,
.path-nav .path-nav-close {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
}
/* line 208, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-close {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none;
  outline: red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
  -o-box-shadow: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
/* line 222, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav:target .path-nav-expander {
  z-index: 1;
}
/* line 228, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander {
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #0fd2ab), color-stop(50%, #0fd2ab), color-stop(50%, #0fd2ab));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0fd2ab, #0fd2ab 50%, #0fd2ab 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0fd2ab, #0fd2ab 50%, #0fd2ab 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#0fd2ab, #0fd2ab 50%, #0fd2ab 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0fd2ab, #0fd2ab 50%, #0fd2ab 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(#0fd2ab, #0fd2ab 50%, #0fd2ab 50%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0.2em 1em 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
/* line 241, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander .cross {
  position: relative;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
/* line 249, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander .cross .cross-h,
.path-nav .path-nav-expander .cross .cross-v {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* line 259, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander .cross .cross-h {
  width: 8px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
/* line 267, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav .path-nav-expander .cross .cross-v {
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

/* line 277, ../sass/menu.scss */
.path-nav-top-right .path-nav-expander {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #143da5), color-stop(50%, #133a9c), color-stop(50%, #103081));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#143da5, #133a9c 50%, #103081 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#143da5, #133a9c 50%, #103081 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#143da5, #133a9c 50%, #103081 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#143da5, #133a9c 50%, #103081 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(#143da5, #133a9c 50%, #103081 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="menu" class="path-nav path-nav-bottom-left">
  <a href="#menu" class="path-nav-expander">
    <div class="cross">
      <div class="cross-h"></div>
      <div class="cross-v"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="path-nav-close"></a>
  <ul id='uItem'>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch" >1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="launch" o>10</a></li>   
  </ul>
</nav>
```